How to determine a threshold value to label a dataset of transformation data?
i have a set of data that is the position and rotations of a human body limbs. I want to label this data that indicates which limb is in contact with a surface (for example if one foot is in contact with ground, it labels the corresponding foot_label = 1 and the other foot_label =0). so if it is above the surface (ground) it means that it is not in contact with the floor. At the moment, what i can think of is a kth precentile method that measures the threshold of 50,20,and 70.. (if that makes sense). what could be a better apprtoach to this ? does anyone know any better statistical way for this type of classification?
